# python/dataframe - merge duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| id | year | data_1 | data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | nan | 11 |
| A | 2019 | abc | 11 |
| A | 2020 | nan | 22 |
| B | 2019 | 345 | nan |
| B | 2019 | nan | 456 |
| B | 2020 | 234 | 33 |

I want to identify duplicated rows based on some columns ("id" and "year" in this case) and merge the rest columns of them i.e. for a columns of an id at a year, keep the non-np.nan value:

| id | year | data_1 | data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019 | abc | 11 |
| A | 2020 | nan | 22 |
| B | 2019 | 345 | 456 |
| B | 2020 | 234 | 33 |

I can find all duplicated rows (which is easy) but can't think of how to "merge" by replacing np.nan with values.

Comment: @timgeb no there can be more.

Comment: okay, understood

Comment: @timgeb Ha sorry, if you mean for each id, year, and *column*, then yes there is always at most one non-nan value. Actually, there will only be two duplicated rows. So there can't be more than 1 non-nan value for each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that will work in this particular case is taking the max per group:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year'], as_index=False).max()
```

output:

```
  id  year  data_1  data_2
0  A  2019   123.0    11.0
1  A  2020     NaN    22.0
2  B  2019   345.0   456.0
3  B  2020   234.0    33.0
```

However, this might not if you have duplicates without NaNs, in this case please provide an updated example and the rules for merging.

Here is a quick fix of the above for mixed types. Convert to string, do the merge, convert back to float. However, mixed types in a single column is not really good practice.

```
(df.fillna('').astype(str)
   .groupby(['id', 'year'], as_index=False).max()
   .astype(float, errors='ignore')
   .replace('', float('nan'))
)
```

Comment: What if there are non-numerical values like string?

Comment: please provide an example and the expected output

Comment: @GrumpyCivet I provided a fix. Do you really have mixed strings and floats in the same column?

Comment: actually, there will only be "string and np.nan" and "float and np.nan" (if you consider np.nan as float, which is true rigorously speaking, then yes)

Comment: OK, then fillna with empty string (if not an issue) in the string columns and the first answer will work

Comment: sorry to bother...can we do this on selected columns only without actually merging rows? e.g. do this on data_1 and then this columns becomes [abc, abc, nan, 345, 345, 234] while the rest columns stay unchanged

Comment: You mean you want to keep the same rows and `ffill`? If this doesn't help, please open an new question as this is a different problem